# C++ Awesomium setting up listener problems

Tags: c++, listener, awesomium

I have an odd error I can't figure out.
I am using Awesomium(latest ver) with C++ and I want to create a listener to connect the JS to the running program.

I have included the /include and /lib folders correctly,
I am also including necessary headers

```
#include <Awesomium/WebCore.h>
#include <Awesomium/STLHelpers.h>
#include <Awesomium/JSObject.h>
#include <Awesomium/WebViewListener.h>
```

However, visual studio keeps saying there's something wrong with my code

```
class BrowserListener : public Awesomium::WebViewListener
{
public:

    virtual void onCallback(Awesomium::WebView* caller,         const std::wstring& objectName,
                            const std::wstring& callbackName,   const Awesomium::JSArray& args) 
    {
    // Check starts here


        if (objectName == L"app" && callbackName == L"settings") {
            std::cout << "callback called with " << args.size() << " args\n";
        }
    }

};
```

It underlines **Awesomium::WebViewListener** as red, saying: 
*Namespace Awesomium, not a class or struct name.
Namespace Awesomium has no member class WebViewListener*

This is the part I can't solve,
please help :)

edit: to be clear, I am able to use awesomium to load sites as intended. It's just the listener object that refuses to work

Answer (score 0):

`WebViewListener` is a namespace nested in the `Awesomium` namespace, not a class. Change the base class to `Awesomium::WebViewListener::Load`.